# Get alerts when someone sends you a message in Skype chat and you're offline

Tags: skype-for-web

I use Skype to keep up to date with several people at work, we also tend to use the chat conversation as an informal feed and in a way an alternative to emails, so sometimes we leave messages on there for each other when the person is offline.

Is there a way to setup a email notification so that it can alert us that "John Doe left a message, but you were offline, go online to see it" or something along those lines?

Comment: I believe the message doesn't send unless you're online. Therefore I don't think there would be anything.

Comment: Are you referring to Skype inside outlook.com or to the standalone desktop client?

Comment: Standalone clinet

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/q/321283/90668

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the installable software and not a web application.